# Update Command Not working mysqli

Tags: php, post, mysqli

```
<?php include('header.php'); 
include('config.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $link1=mysqli_real_escape_string($cone,$_POST['link1']);
    $link2=mysqli_real_escape_string($cone,$_POST['link2']);
    $link3=mysqli_real_escape_string($cone,$_POST['link3']);
    $link4=mysqli_real_escape_string($cone,$_POST['link4']);
    $link5=mysqli_real_escape_string($cone,$_POST['link5']);
    $sql = "update path set 1='hello' where id=1";
    if (mysqli_query($cone,$sql))
    {
        header("location:section_6.php?done");
    }
}
?>
```

What am i doing wrong here ? The Cone variable is defined in config.php but i can't get the update working and there's no error.

Comment: `set 1` - is `1` the actual column name?

Comment: yes there are 5 columns named as 1,2,3,4,5 respectively.

Comment: Consult the duplicate the question was closed with.

Comment: Related: [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: @AshishChoudhary You should rename those columns for sure.

Comment: @FirstOne why is that? I don't see anything related to this. See the duplicate; that's the reason here.

Comment: Don't use numbers as column names.